# Как записать процент в JavaScript, чтобы он не считал мне процент, а был строкой?

Tags: javascript, строки, проценты

В общем я только учусь в js. Взяла задачу, сделать диаграмму, чтобы при клике на сектор, закрашивалась определенная область. Код работает, но не корректно из-за процента. Он делит число на 100 вместо того чтобы записать число и процент в строку.Можно ли поправить это в данной функции?

```js
function setTransform(scaleArg) {
        mark.style.transform = ("scale(" + scaleArg + "%)"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

scale выглядит так:

```
scale(x, y)
```

то есть принимает значение (`float`) по X и Y. Где значения от 0 до 1 - уменьшение масштаба, от 1 и выше - увеличение. Например `scale(1.5, 1)`  увеличит  1,5 раза по оси X

А то что вы написали - вообще никаким правилам не поддаётся, т.к. нет такого правила `scale(%)`

Comment: Поняла, большое спасибо, не там проблему искала) в css надо было смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

`scale(x)` принимает значение и увеличивает объект в `x` раз.

Также, если например нужно увеличить или уменьшить объект в `x%`, то можно это число разделить на 100. Например, чтобы увеличить объект на 10%, нужно 110/100:

```js
function setTransform(scaleArg) {
 mark.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleArg + ')';
}
```